# Prove that $ax = \cos(\pi\cdot x)$ has exactly one solution

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $ax = \cos(\pi\cdot x)$ has exactly one solution when $0 \le x \le 1$. a is any positive real number.

I can solve this question fine by drawing $\cos(\pi\cdot x)$ out but it's considered informal. I need help on a written proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by showing that $cos(\pi x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,1)$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\pi x) < 0$, as if $\cos(\pi a) = \cos(\pi b)$ for $a < b$ then by the mean value theorem we have $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\pi c) = 0$ for some $a < c < b$. $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\pi x) = -\sin(\pi x)$, which you can show is less than $0$ on $(0,1)$ by interpreting $\sin(\pi x)$ it as the ratio of the opposite side of a triangle to the hypotenuse.

Comment: "equivalent" is a strong word...

Comment: @Moron: Sorry. It's very close though, as it must be at least non-increasing, but I'll change it.

Comment: $\cos (\pi x)$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$, not increasing (derivative is $-\pi \ \sin(\pi x)$ which is negative in $(0,1)$). Also, the function could oscillate wildly yet have only one intersection point, so I would not call "equivalent" close. +1 though :-)

Comment: @Moron: Darn. That's what I meant. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Is this sufficient for a 4 mark question?

Comment: The "you can show" part means that you should work that part out for yourself.

Comment: @Alex thanks, one more thing... can you explain why $\cos(\pi a) = \cos(\pi b)$ for $a < b$? I'm not quite sure about that part.

Comment: @meiryo: That is not true, in fact you are trying to prove that it is not true. What i did is *assume* that it is true in order to derive a contradiction, thus showing that it cannot be true.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm curious as I want to know what needs fixing.

Comment: @Alex Okay, I get it now.> $cos(\pi x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,1)$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\pi x) > 0$ shouldn't it be $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(\pi x) < 0$?

Comment: @meiryo: Yes, sorry that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Alex: what about the hypothesis that $a>0$? I do not see it mentioned or even used in your post.

Comment: And, actually the derivative is $- \pi \sin(\pi x)$ and talking about triangles is not right for $x \ge 1/2$ (unless you use mention $\sin(\pi -x ) = \sin x$ or something like that). Sorry, I will have to retract the +1 till you edit it.

Comment: Alex: Care to address the remarks above, by Aryabhata and me? As far as I am concerned, the present version of your post is far from being satisfying.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: on the interval $[0,1]$, the function $x\mapsto ax$ is increasing from $0$ to $a$ and the function $x\mapsto\cos(\pi x)$ is decreasing from $1$ to $-1$.

Validity check: one should be able to prove that the unique solution in $[0,1]$ is in $(0,1/2)$ and that every point in this interval can be made solution for a suitable value of the slope parameter $a$.

Answer (score 2):

A sketch is fully persuasive.  However, the problem is intended to test your control over certain tools.  So it is difficult to give an appropriate answer unless one knows the context in which the problem arises. I will assume that this context is a somewhat theoretically minded calculus course.

We will use a standard trick.  When we are interested in the *relation* between two functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, it is often useful to examine the behaviour of their *difference*, that is, to study $f(x)$, where $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$.

Let $f(x)=ax-\cos x$.  We wish to show that $f(x)=0$ for *exactly* one value of $x$ between $0$ and $\pi$.

Note that $f(0)=-1$ and $f(\pi)=a\pi +1$.  Thus $f(0)$ is negative, and (since $a$ is positive), $f(\pi)$ is positive.  Since $f$ is continuous in our interval, it follows by the **Intermediate Value Theorem** that $f(c)=0$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $\pi$.  (Indeed, as $x$ ranges over our interval, $f(x)$ takes on all values between $-1$ and $a\pi+1$.)

Note that we have not *proved* that $f$ is continuous in our interval, we have just asserted it.  And of course we took it for granted that $\cos(0)=1$ and $\cos(\pi)=-1$.  In the context of this problem, you are almost certainly not expected to prove continuity.  But *asserting* it is important, since it shows that you know that one needs certain conditions on $f$ in order to be able to use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Finally, we show that there cannot be *more* than one one value of $x$ in our interval such that $f(x)=0$. Here you are likely expected to use the derivative.

Note that $f'(x)=a+\sin x$.  Between $0$ and $\pi$, $\sin x \ge 0$, so between $0$ and $\pi$, $f'(x)>0$.  It follows that $f$ is an *increasing* function in our interval. So in our interval, $f(x)$ can be $0$ for at most one value of $x$.

We have proved that $f(x)=0$ for *at least* one $x$ in our interval, and also for *at most* one $x$, so $f(x)=0$ for *exactly* one value of $x$ in our interval.